# I can't change my emacs alias in Unix?

Tags: unix, emacs, emacs24, tcsh

I'm trying to add alias emacs "emacs24" to my .aliases folder, but whenever I try using emacs it keeps using version 22. I'm using the t shell btw

Answer (score 1):

For Bash,add your aliases to .bashrc:

`alias e="/usr/bin/emacs24"`

.aliases is not used by bash.

For csh and tcsh, add them to .cshrc

`alias e "/usr/bin/emacs24"`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work either.

Comment: My emacs is called `/usr/bin/emacs-24.3`.  Try `ls /usr/bin | grep emacs`.